# Seeking an approach to maintain a drupal site from a mobile platform

Tags: theming

I have a client who needs to update their drupal site almost exclusively from their iPhone and iPad. They need to be able to upload images from iOS Photos. I have some ideas on how to approach, but I'm wondering if anybody in the community has encountered this situation and can suggest a combination of theme & modules that will help me get most of the way there.
thanks

Comment: [Drupalgap](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgap)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the qualitiy of this app, but could

[Drupad - Drupal on the go (iPhone/iPad App)](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/drupad-drupal-on-the-go/id378485000?mt=8)

help you?

**App description:**

Features for webmaster

- Manage any number of websites
- Create and edit content (CCK, Fields API support)
- Search and edit user accounts
- Read, post, moderate comments
- Moderate your content
- Mollom™ support
- Promote, sticky, publish, unpublish nodes
- Manage your users, send them email etc.
- Gravatar™ fallback for User's picture
- Drag to refresh and to load more content
- Built-in web browser
- Optimized to be fast in 3G or Wifi

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Adminimal Responsive Admin Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme).  Integrated with [Adminimal Administration Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_admin_menu)

Answer (score 0):

So after a quick run through of the Admiminal Theme and its co-module Adminimal Administration Menu, I think out of the box its the going to be the right choice for our project. Its working pretty good out of the box, I can upload images from my iPhone 6+ w/ relative ease. I was initially interested in the Drupad app, but it looks like its not being maintained and is challenging to set up. As I'm doing this work for a client, we need to have an experience that is easy and as painless as possible.

I think Adminimal will get us most of the way there, w/ some modifications and the reasonable amount of customizing and coaxing. 
Thanks for all that weighed in.